# Wikipedia model training parameters

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gensim

Pretrained models of English and other language wikipedia are available here...

https://wikipedia2vec.github.io/wikipedia2vec/pretrained/

What is the difference between 100d and 500d in case of English wikipedia?

And what does these parameters mean to training (window=5, iteration=10, negative=15)

Answer (score 0):

The values 100d, 500d refer to the word embedding dimension, see [Word2Vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec), a vocabulary is built from the unique words, and each word is embedded in the form of a vector of the given embedding dimension.

A window of 5 would refer to the [n-gram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) model where 5 word window is taken to decide the context.

I'm not really sure about iteration and negative however.